# How to store the current version of an instance? Store reference to specific instance?

Tags: versioning, configuration, separation-of-concerns, storage, grails

I'm working on a project with has different checklists (questions and answers) associated with an entity (Protocol).  There is a business requirement to have these questions be altered in the future and when a new entity is created it would be associated with the current checklist.

Example:

Lets say there is a checklist and has 21 questions (the actual questions are nested with questions having other questions but I believe this is out of the scope of this question).  This would be version `1.0`.  Something changes and now there are 22 questions and the version would be bumped up to `1.1`.

When a new `Protocol` is created, it needs to have a `Checklist` associated with it - the current `Checklist`.

Simplified classes:

```
class Checklist {
    String version
    List<ChecklistQuestion> checklistQuestions
}

class ChecklistAnswerSet {
    Checklist checklist
    List<ChecklistAnswer> checklistAnswer
}

class Protocol {
    ChecklistAnswerSet checklistAnswerSet
    ...
}
```

New `Protocol`'s are created within the `ProtocolService`; the child `checklistAnswerSet` is also created here as well but needs to refer to the current `Checklist` instance.

We are working with a grails backend and it's extremely easy getting references to instances by their fields:

```
Checklist checklist = Checklist.findByVersion('1.1')
```

I could drop this in my `ProtocolService` to get the current instance but I know this isn't a good idea.  Any changes to this version would require code changes to the Service and although I could avoid a redeploy (grails magic), this feels completely wrong.

Where do I store this `1.1`? In a configuration file? In the database? Or am I completely wrong and my design needs a complete rework?

Initially, I was storing this `1.1` data within a generic key/value table we have in the database called `System_Property`, but it just felt wrong.  My gut reaction is to use a configuration file (there are other `Checklist`'s and therefore other current versions that would also go here), but a coworker is saying only environmental settings go in config files.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete solution merely storing the version would not enough, simply because

1. You could delete a question in the subsequent version and you still want to keep the answers for the previous versions
2. When you alter a question, the if the answer still linked to the changed question, it won't make sense once the question is changed

So ideally, you would want to store something like this,

```
class Checklist {
    List<ChecklistVersion> checklistVersions
}

class ChecklistVersion {
    String version
    List<ChecklistQuestion> checklistQuestions
}

class ChecklistAnswerSet {
    ChecklistVersion checklistVersion
    List<ChecklistAnswer> checklistAnswer
}

class Protocol {
    ChecklistAnswerSet checklistAnswerSet
    ...
}
```

by adding a separate version object, you would not have issues if a question is deleted, or new one added or existing one changed

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I did not go into detail for the `ChecklistQuestion`/`ChecklistAnswer` classes but the answer has a reference to the question which is backed by a foreign key so a deletion would not occur (a question may not appear on future checklist though).  I believe altering of questions would only occur to correct minor errors; we would create a new question if the meaning actually changed and replace it within the new checklist.